# Is there any way to skip a specific activity after performing spcific actions

Tags: android

I have activity say A->B->C. If user has performed actions on activity B and results have been generated on C. Then when user next time tries to go to activity B from A...It should move to result page in activity C.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do that. Here are the steps which you can follow:

1. Create a flag variable `flag` in your Activity C and mark it as 1, if the results are published in Activity C. Remember to save this value in your Shared Preferences, once you have populated the results (or your logic) on Activity C.
2. In your Activity A, fetch the value of the variable `flag` from Shared Preferences, having a default value as 0. If you find the value to be 1, it means, the user interacted with the Activity B earlier. With this, you can skip calling (starting) activity B and simply go to (start) activity C.

Remember, the value of `flag` will always remain **1** once the user interacted with activity B, and hence, he/she will never be able to navigate to Activity B in future, until this value is set to **0** and saved in Shared Preferences

Comment: or it could be a boolean flag with a more straight forward description, e.g. shouldGoStraightToActivityC

Comment: @NikosHidalgo Yes. That is truly acceptable too. :)

Comment: @NikosHidalgo However, I do think that checking inside Activity A, before launching Activity B is far better than what RobCo posted as an answer. Doing as he said, will lead to a quick Flicker, I suppose. Also, instead of launching an unwanted activity, it is better to launch the desired activity itself.

Comment: I agree! That's why I commented on your answer as I find it the simplest solution.

Comment: lunchbreak over, have to go back to work now I'm afraid!

Answer (score 0):

In the `onCreate` of activity B, you can check if you should go to activity C instead and if so, start activity C and finish the current activity (B).